# make calculator using C language

Tags: c, string, calculator

Hello I'm trying to make a calculator where the user puts the exercise (into a string) and transferred to the four functions of multiplication division addition and subtraction my functions have been ready, but I have two major problems which I need your help.

So that's my first problem is that when I put my functions (char function) my  program crashes but when I run the same function (in a main function) it works without problems. so I would love to know why this happens and how I can fix it.

The second problem is how I can make all function to make herself several times (recursively) so if you can help me make a function to do this I appreciate it.

Another small problem I would be happy if you can help me with it and make the function return (return) the original string to the next function.

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char multiplication(char str[]);

int main()
{
    char str[99] = "3-5+5*7";
    multiplication(str);
    return(0);
}

char multiplication(char str[])
{
    char strp[99];
    char str1[99] = {0};
    char str2[99];
    char mul[99] = "*";
    char old[99];
    char *rev;
    int i, k, j = 0, aPos, zPos, len;
    int sum,sum1,sum2;
    static char buffer[4096];
    char *p;

    len = strlen(str);
    strcpy (strp, str);
    aPos = zPos = -1;

    for(i =0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] ==  '+' )
        {
            aPos = i;
        }
        else if(str[i] == '*')    
        {
            zPos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(aPos != -1 && zPos != -1)
    {
        for(k=0, i=zPos-1;i>aPos;--i,++k)
        {
            str1[k]=str[i];
        }
    }

    rev = strrev(str1);

    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(strp[i] == '*')
        {
            while(strp[i+1] != '+' || '\0')
            {
                str2[j++] = strp[++i];
            }
        }
    }

    old[0] = '\0';
    strcat(old,str1);
    strcat(old,mul);
    strcat(old,str2);

    sum1 = atoi (str1);
    sum2 = atoi (str2);
    sum = sum1 * sum2;  

    str2[j] = '\0'; 
    sprintf(str2,"%d",sum);

    if(!(p = strstr(str, old)))
        printf("%s",str);
    strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); // Copy characters from 'str' to the new string
    buffer[p-str] = '\0';
    sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", str2, p+strlen(old));
    printf("%s",buffer);
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me I appreciate it very much

Comment: As for solving, your general approach should be taking your string and splitting it into characters. You can then convert the equation to RPN using the [Shunting-Yard Algorithim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). I've implemented this algorithm and it works splendidly.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an exercise with this solution?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21800127 I think that it would be helpful.

Comment: It's best to provide us with as much information as possible. So if you have a problem like "When I do X my program crashes", provide the error code. (If your problem is unexpected behaviour, describe clearly the expected behaviour and what happens instead. And so on.)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this problem in general would be the [Shunting Yard Algorithim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) which converts [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) to [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). I think you will find [this blog](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/) helpful in understanding some implementations of the shunting yard algorithm to create this kind of a solver. I also recommend reading the Wikipedia pages on both the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

With these resources, you will find that the most effective way to convert [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) to [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is to use the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It is then trivial to evaluate your [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) equation in code (with a stack data structure... keep reading). In order to accomplish all of this, I recommend you learn about the [stack data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) and its implementations in C/C++ Check [this implementation of a stack at cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/stackcode.html), [this implementation from the cs department at MIT](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F04/cpp_notes/stack1.html) and [this implementation from the cs department at Boston University](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/stack/array/).

The [cprogramming.com reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/stackcode.html) is more of a C++ implementation because it uses templates. If you JUST want code, check out the [link from MIT](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F04/cpp_notes/stack1.html).